# During Texture Paint, Shadows and Lights Create Distorted Colors

Tags: texture-painting

I am trying to do some basic texture painting in Blender 2.81 but basically cannot see my base colors because shadows and lights shining make everything darker and obscured. I have included the image below to illustrate my dilemma.

What is the optimal environmental setup for texture painting where I can see the colors evenly from all angles?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make changes to your viewport to create a flat color response in the same place you choose matcap or solid, etc.[image]